# Windows Phone - get location of Image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a camera app, and want to store the location of where the Image was taken.

**I'm wondering what the best practice to implement this is?**

I can think of two possible solutions;

1) Get the location directly from the Image. I'm not sure if this is how it works in Windows Phone, but perhaps the location is stored in the Image every time you take one. If so, it would be easy to get it directly from the image.
2) If not, implement a GeoCoordinateWatcher that starts when I open the camera view and stores the location after I've taken the photo and then stops.

Comment: This currently reads more like a statement of fact, rather than an actual question - can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Sorry, I was a little unclear. I've updated the post, hopefully it reads more like a question now. I basically want to know how to get the location of an image, I just added my own thoughts so that you could see I've done some research myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera photos have no location tagged to it. You need to capture the image, then the attempt to get the gps location after the picture is taken and tag it to the image.